# How to map multiple entities to one class in Mapster

Tags: c#, automapper, mapster

In AutoMapper, we can map multiple entities to one, but can't impl in mapster.
Automapper demo code:

Entity:

```
var users = await _userManager.Users
            .AsNoTracking()
            .ProjectTo<UserDto>(new { roles = _roleManager.Roles })              
            .ToListAsync();
```

AutoMapper config:

```
IQueryable<IdentityRole> roles = null;
        CreateMap<User, UserDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Roles, opt => 
                opt.MapFrom(src => 
                    src.Roles
                        .Join(roles, a => a.RoleId, b => b.Id, (a, b) => b.Name)
                        .ToList()
                )
            );
```

There is no parameter in Mapster Querable.ProjectTo() method.
Who can help me see what I should do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly, you are trying to map objects from multiple sources.
Mapster supports this operation. From the [Mapster GitHub repo](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Custom-mapping#multiple-sources):

```
public class SubDto
{
    public string Extra { get; set; }
}

public class Dto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SubDto SubDto { get; set; }
}

public class Poco
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Extra { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to map `SubDto` and `Dto` to `Poco`, you can use the following config:

```
TypeAdapterConfig<(SubDto, Dto), Poco>.NewConfig()
    .Map(dest => dest, src => src.Item1)
    .Map(dest => dest, src => src.Item2);
```

Hope, it helps!